# light weight Key-value pair storage in react JS for web browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storage

I am new in developing react JS. We are creating a Web based application. In Android we will  use SharePreferences to store key-value pair data. What is the equivalent to shared preferences in react JS with Typescript that will support web browser and it should be light weight?

Also in future, we may need to encrypt as well.

Comment: [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)